# Weka 3.8 package manager not working

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I am trying to open the package manager from `Tools tab` and i get the following error:

```
C:\Users\user\wekafiles\repCache\MultiObjectiveEvolutionaryFuzzyClassifier\versions.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
    java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    weka.core.packageManagement.DefaultPackageManager.getRepositoryPackageVersions(DefaultPackageManager.java:294)
    weka.core.WekaPackageManager.getRepositoryPackageVersions(WekaPackageManager.java:1734)
    weka.gui.PackageManager.getPackagesAndEstablishLookup(PackageManager.java:2389)
    weka.gui.PackageManager.getAllPackages(PackageManager.java:2445)
    weka.gui.PackageManager.<init>(PackageManager.java:1517)
    weka.gui.GUIChooserApp$11$1.run(GUIChooserApp.java:822)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown     Source)
    at weka.core.packageManagement.DefaultPackageManager.getRepositoryPackageVersions(DefaultPackageManager.java:294)
    at  weka.core.WekaPackageManager.getRepositoryPackageVersions(WekaPackageManager.java:1734)
    at     weka.gui.PackageManager.getPackagesAndEstablishLookup(PackageManager.java:2389)
    at weka.gui.PackageManager.getAllPackages(PackageManager.java:2445)
    at weka.gui.PackageManager.<init>(PackageManager.java:1517)
    at weka.gui.GUIChooserApp$11$1.run(GUIChooserApp.java:822)
A problem has occurred whilst trying to get all package information. Trying a cache refresh...
Refresh in progress. Please wait...
```

then it downloads the Default Package Manager:

```
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 13 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 16 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 28 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 50 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 67 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 75 KB
...[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1666 KB
```

and outputs the same error again.

note: file versions.txt is properly placed in `C:\Users\user\wekafiles\repCache\MultiObjectiveEvolutionaryFuzzyClassifier` directory

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, the directory exists in your file system is MultiObje`c`tiveEvolutionaryFuzzyClassifier without a 'c' . Change it by yourself, you'll get it work well:)

Comment: WOW. Seriously? I have been struggling the whole day for this issue. Thanks a lot.